# How to add pagination in UITableView.?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I parse data from API for the first page and add it to `UITableView`, now pages can be multiple lets say 100, I also get total number of pages from API also. but how will i implement it in tableView for every page and show indicator while scrolling. Have a look at my code

```
NSURL *theURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://qa.networc.in:1336/api/dispatcher/rideScheduled/:1"];
NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:theURL      cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:20.0f];

//Specify method of request(Get or Post)
[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

//Pass some default parameter(like content-type etc.)
[theRequest setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[theRequest setValue:@"application/json; charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

[theRequest addValue:token forHTTPHeaderField:@"x-access-token"];
NSURLResponse *theResponse = NULL;
NSError *theError = NULL;

NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:theRequest returningResponse:&theResponse error:&theError];
if (responseData == nil)
{
    return;
}

NSDictionary *dataDictionaryResponse = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:0 error:&theError];
NSLog(@"url to send request= %@",theURL);
NSLog(@"%@",dataDictionaryResponse);



NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];

NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [session dataTaskWithRequest:theRequest
                                        completionHandler:
                              ^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

                                  NSLog(@"Response:%@ %@\n", response, error);
                                  if(error == nil)
                                  {

                                      NSString * text = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                                      NSLog(@"Data = %@",text);
                                  }

                                  dictionary = [[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil]objectForKey:@"data"];

                                  NSArray *total =  [dictionary objectForKey:@"total"];
                                  NSLog(@"latlop %@", total);




                                  NSArray *IDArray = [dictionary objectForKey:@"docs"];
                                  for (NSDictionary *Dict in IDArray)
                                  {

                                      NSMutableDictionary *temp = [NSMutableDictionary new];
                                      [temp setObject:[Dict objectForKey:@"_id"] forKey:@"_id"];

                                      NSLog(@"temp %@", temp );

                                      NSString *booknumber = [Dict objectForKey:@"bookingNumber"];
                                      if([booknumber length] != 0)
                                          [temp setObject:booknumber forKey:@"bookingNumber"];

                                      NSMutableDictionary *stp1 = [Dict objectForKey:@"stop1"];

                                      if ([[stp1 allKeys] containsObject:@"address"]) {

                                          [temp setObject:[stp1 objectForKey:@"address"] forKey:@"address"];




                                          ];

                                      }

                                      NSMutableDictionary *stp2 = [Dict objectForKey:@"stop2"];

                                      if ([[stp2 allKeys] containsObject:@"address"]) {

                                          [temp setObject:[stp2 objectForKey:@"address"] forKey:@"address1"];


                                          NSArray *latlongstp2 =  [stp2 objectForKey:@"location"];
                                          [temp setObject:[latlongstp2 objectAtIndex:0] forKey:@"latitude"];
                                          [temp setObject:[latlongstp2 objectAtIndex:1] forKey:@"longitude"];

                                      }



                                      NSMutableDictionary *currentloc = [Dict objectForKey:@"currentLocation"];

                                      if ([[currentloc allKeys] containsObject:@"address"]) {

                                          [temp setObject:[currentloc objectForKey:@"address"] forKey:@"address1"];


                                      }


                                      [getid addObject:temp];

                                  }


                                  if (getid.count>0)
                                  {
                                      [self updateTable];
                                  }



                              }];

[task resume];

}


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;    //count of section
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {


    return [getid count];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell: (UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (indexPath.row == [getid count] - 1 ) {

    }
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ScheduleTableViewCell *cell   = [tableView      dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.BookingId.text  = [[getid        objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"_id"];
    cell.BookingNo.text  = [[getid objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"bookingNumber"];
    cell.stop1.text  = [[getid objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"address"];
    cell.stop2.text = [[getid objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"address1"];
    cell.Currentloc.text = [[getid objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]  objectForKey:@"address"];


    return cell;
}
```

Comment: The are number of techniques out there on internet for implementing pagination along with good examples. Try those and modify them to suit your need. Here is a good example - http://www.iosnomad.com/blog/2014/4/21/fluent-pagination

Comment: @TheRohanSanap sir i don't want to use third party library

Comment: I don't think the example link I specified use any third party library for pagination. They have merely explained logic with example. Anyways, here is another one - https://grokswift.com/rest-tableview-in-swift/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many way to achieve this like following way:

- First you need to create one global `NSMutableArray` that load in `TableView` Delegates and `DataSaurce`.
- Now on your api call you need to add That records in global Array.
- On last cell or the `tableview` you can call it again with next page URL based on your API and reload table on each Call
- You can use for loadMore many thirdParty library available on github:

https://github.com/OpenFibers/DragRefreshAndLoadMoreTableDemo

https://github.com/Abizern/PartialTable

https://github.com/robertmryan/UITableView-Bottom-Refresh

Based On your code:

**in .h class**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
   NSURL* nextURL;
    int currentPage;

}
```

**in .M Class**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    currentPage = 1;

    [self LoadData];
    [super viewDidLoad];

}


-(void)LoadData
{

    NSURL *theURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://qa.networc.in:1336/api/dispatcher/rideScheduled/:%d",currentPage]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:theURL      cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:20.0f];

    //Specify method of request(Get or Post)
    [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

    //Pass some default parameter(like content-type etc.)
    [theRequest setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [theRequest setValue:@"application/json; charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    [theRequest addValue:token forHTTPHeaderField:@"x-access-token"];
    NSURLResponse *theResponse = NULL;
    NSError *theError = NULL;

    NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:theRequest returningResponse:&theResponse error:&theError];
    if (responseData == nil)
    {
        return;
    }

    NSDictionary *dataDictionaryResponse = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:0 error:&theError];
    NSLog(@"url to send request= %@",theURL);
    NSLog(@"%@",dataDictionaryResponse);



    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];

    NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [session dataTaskWithRequest:theRequest
                                            completionHandler:
                                  ^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

                                      NSLog(@"Response:%@ %@\n", response, error);
                                      if(error == nil)
                                      {

                                          NSString * text = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                                          NSLog(@"Data = %@",text);
                                      }


                                      currentPage ++;
                                      dictionary = [[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil]objectForKey:@"data"];

                                      NSArray *total =  [dictionary objectForKey:@"total"];
                                      NSLog(@"latlop %@", total);


                                      [getid addObjectsFromArray:total];

                                       [self updateTable];

                                  }];

    [task resume];
}
```

Comment: why you doing too much code when you get response. once you get responce you just need to add this in to your master array and reload it. Do code in CellForRowIndex based on your master array.

Comment: ok sir i tried to work on it

Comment: sir how will i add next page in url from cellfroindexpath method

Comment: create one variable that assign nexturl. mean once you call at the success time you create next url with new page number and assing it to the next time calling string

Comment: sir can you edit in my code for a little bit hint please, if it is possible

Comment: ok sir till that i tried to implement it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113372/discussion-between-nitin-gohel-and-sandeep-tomar).

Comment: i updated code can you try to impliemnt like that

Comment: yes sir thanks for your answer i am working on it please wait some time

Comment: have yo done? the pagination

Comment: no yet sir, Actualy i get total number of page in getid, but i am not able to scroll in that way, because i need to add some  value on cells  according to page wise sir

Comment: i am getting response from viewdidload method, is it necessary to again parse response in load data method?

Comment: sir how will current page increases ?

Answer (score 3):

declare a global variable pagingCount and initialize it with 1 in viewdidload.

make this change in your data fetcher method.

```
NSURL *theURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://qa.networc.in:1336/api/dispatcher/rideScheduled/:%d",pagingCount];
```

now you will pass this paging count & call your data fetcher method whenever the last cell is about to display.
update the paging count with +1

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell: (UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
if (indexPath.row == [getid count] - 1 ) {
//call your method of fetching data with paging which will be increased with 1
//increase the pagingCount
pagingCount += 1;

//call your data fetcher
            }
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was done same using following code

```
#pragma mark --- UIScrollView Delegate Method ---

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    float offset = (scrollView.contentOffset.y - (scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.size.height));
    btnloadMore.hidden = YES;

    if (offset >= 0 && offset <= 105)
    {
        if(isLoadMoreCheck == TRUE)
        {
            NSLog(@"Hi");
            //btnloadMore.hidden = NO;
            [self addMoreData];
        }
    }

    NSLog(@"Scroll : %f",offset);
}

- (void)addMoreData
{
    isLoadMoreCheck = FALSE;
    isLoadMore = TRUE;
    currentPage++;
    [self getNewsFeeds:currentPage];// Here you can call your method for load next page data
}
```