# Handling pagination when downloading items for uicollecyionview/uitableview?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, pagination, uicollectionview

i’want to use pagination in a controller that displays posts downloaded from a server so that I don’t download all posts together . Any help on how to achieve this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37537463/how-to-add-pagination-in-uitableview

Answer (score 0):

I tend to use this library for swift.

https://github.com/pronebird/UIScrollView-InfiniteScroll

```
tableView.addInfiniteScroll { [weak self] (tableView) -> Void in
  // update table view, pagination.
}
```

Comment: what about a solution without third party libraries? I'm trying to look at this repo code to implement my own solution but I'm not familiar with objective c